# Trace source of deprecation warnings in rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, warnings, deprecated

When running my functional tests, I'm getting the following warning in one of the test cases but I can't pinpoint where it's coming from:

`gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/record_identifier.rb:76: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id`

Unfortunately that's the only line of the backtrace that's shown, even if I run it with `rake test --trace`, and there is no more information in `log/test.log`.

How can I get the full backtrace for this warning or otherwise figure out which line in my code is causing it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To solve this you could enable the full debugging information. [(see the help)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Deprecation.html)

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.debug = true
```

As @Eric Anderson says it should be placed after Rails loads (i.e. after `require 'rails/all'` in application.rb) but before bundler runs to catch deprecation warning in gems (i.e. before `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)` in application.rb).

You can add a condition, like `if ENV["DEBUG"]` or `if environment == :test` to leave this in your config.

---

Update: as [@Dorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12544391/dorian) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671959/trace-source-of-deprecation-warnings-in-rails-tests/8797737?noredirect=1#comment137589688_8797737) the method is deprecated on recent Rails versions, so you should use:

```
Rails.application.deprecators.debug = true
```

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling debug= on ActiveSupport::Deprecation is deprecated and will be removed from Rails (use Rails.application.deprecators.debug= instead) (called from block in <main> at /app/config/environments/test.rb:34)

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue. A gem was causing a deprecation warning but I had no idea which gem since Rail's message only shows the last bit of the callstack in my code. Add the following:

```
module ActiveSupport::Deprecation
  class << self
    def deprecation_message_with_debugger(callstack, message = nil)
      debugger
      deprecation_message_without_debugger callstack, message
    end
    alias_method_chain :deprecation_message, :debugger
  end
end
```

Placed this after Rails loads (i.e. after `require 'rails/all'` in application.rb) but before bunder runs to catch deprecation warning in gems (i.e. before `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)` in application.rb).

Now when a deprecation warning is encountered you are dropped in the debugger. You can either leave this in (and surround with a `if Rails.env.test?`) or remove it when you have found your issues.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable solution. I'm chuckling to myself because with the release of Rails 5,  `alias_method_chain` itself is deprecated. I guess it's fine to use `alias_method_chain` to find where `alias_method_chain` is being used

Comment: You can you Module#prepend now.

Answer (score 1):

When I get this kind of warning in my tests it is usually because I am using mocking model objects and am not providing all the methods that active record provides for real.

A good starting point would be the rails code itself. Looking at the source code for the `action_pack` gem which is referenced, the method that is causing the error is `dom_id`. That method generates an id for an object for use on a page. It seems to be called in a couple of places internally (unless you are calling it directly of course!) but the most likely cause appears to be calling `form_for` on an object.

Comment: I was hoping for a more general answer, not specifically for this error, but it makes sense: stepping in through the rails source was exactly what I ended up doing; it's probably the only way to do it. I added a `breakpoint unless record.kind_of?(ActiveRecord::Base)` above that line in actionpack so I could call `where` and get the full stack. (Turns out it was a `content_tag_for`...)

Comment: Right, I see. I couldn't figure out a way of getting any more information other than stepping into the rails code and working back. You don't have to accept my answer if it doesn't answer what you wanted!

Answer (score 0):

The new way of doing this is:

```
Rails.application.deprecators.debug = true
```