# How to detect what causes a deprecation warning in Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rake

When I do `bundle exec rake -T` (or `bundle exec rake`), I get deprecation warnings:

```
Andrews-Air:nabu agrimm$ bundle exec rake --trace -T
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
rake about                               # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
[snip]
```

Although not really relevant, here's the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.22.2'

gem 'mysql2'

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'compass-rails'

  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'libv8'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'to-csv', :require => 'to_csv'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'oai'
gem 'analytical'

gem 'country-select'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'sass-rails',  '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'meta_search', '>= 1.1.0.pre'

gem 'devise', '2.2.3'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.12.0'

gem 'squeel'
gem 'nilify_blanks'

gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'

gem 'unicorn'

gem 'ruby-filemagic'

gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-ext'
gem 'capistrano-unicorn'

gem 'rollbar', '~> 2.8.3'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

gem 'progress_bar'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 2'
gem 'quiet_assets'
gem 'roo', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'roo-xls', :github => 'roo-rb/roo-xls', :ref => '0a5ef88'
gem 'streamio-ffmpeg'
gem 'rake'

gem 'rmagick'

gem 'whenever', :require => false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'turn', '~> 0.8.3', :require => false
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'sextant'
  gem 'thin'

  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'

  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'

  gem 'letter_opener'

  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-sunspot'

  gem 'rb-inotify', :require => RUBY_PLATFORM.include?('linux') ? 'rb-inotify' : false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => RUBY_PLATFORM.include?('darwin') ? 'rb-fsevent' : false
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'rubocop'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

Doing a `git grep -i last_comment` indicates it's not in my code - presumably it's in a third-party gem.

How do I work out what causes the deprecation warnings?

Comment: As a workaround, requiring `rake` to be earlier than 11.0 removed the deprecation notice.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I find it easier modifying the the line from `warn` to `raise` in `rake-11.1.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:10`.

For me the offending gems are rspec ([fixed in 3.4.4](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/2197)) and rubocop ([fixed in 0.38.0](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/commit/88a200e59e10868450ceb4316ffc600d9a09b95c)).

Comment: I have changed warn to raise in task_manger.rb, but I still can not use rake (db:migrate). I have also noticed that I have multiple rake versions in my gems directory, should I remove newer?

Comment: Updating rspec-core to 3.4.4 & rspec-rails to 3.4.2 resolved it.

Answer (score 28):

Try updating `gem "rspec-rails", "~> 3.4.4"`, that resolved the deprecation warnings for me.

Comment: rspec-core 3.4.2 still had this warning for me. Updating to 3.4.4 resolved it. See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2210.

Comment: Gemfile: `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4.2'`,
Console: `$ bundle update rspec rspec-rails`

Answer (score 5):

You can *recursively* grep your gems, with:

```
grep -r last_comment /path/to/gems
```

Comment: Doing `grep -r last_comment` gives `grep: warning: recursive search of stdin`

Comment: Sorry. I've updated my answer. /path/to/gems depends on your installation.

Comment: If you have multiple projects, then wouldn't `/path/to/gems` include the gems for all of your projects?

Comment: If it helps, the following prints all the paths to grep for your current project: `for gem in $(bundle list | awk '{print $2}'); do bundle show "$gem"; done`

Answer (score 5):

It is not [rspec fault](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2207), the error comes from rake there was a [commit](https://github.com/ruby/rake/commit/3948349a82a2522f1d8293093164ef395bee542d) a couple of weeks ago that added the warning, there was a follow up [here](https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues/119).

Seems that Rspec already complies in using `last_description` over `last_comment`. If possible try to update to a newer version of `rspec-core` Gem, like @chris-scott suggested. I ran to do the trick

`bundle update rspec-core`

Answer (score 5):

As described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8797737/3700317), you can do:

```
# application.rb
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.debug = true
```

This will give you full stack trace of deprecation.